# Python - Cast Float/String to Integer in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

I'm facing an issue with this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [1.0, 2.0, '', 45.0, 0.0]}
df_d = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_d = df_d['B'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x != '' else None)
```

Expected output:

```
   A      B
0  1      1
1  2      2
2  3   None
3  4     45
4  5      0
```

Real output:

```
   A     B
0  1   1.0
1  2   2.0
2  3   NaN
3  4  45.0
4  5   0.0
```

I've read many topics on this site but no one seems to work for my case.
My task is to cast to integer float values, and to replace with None the empty strings.

I tried with:

```
df_d['B'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if not isinstance(x,str) else None)
```

Same output.

I also tried with:

```
df_d['B'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x != '' else '')
```

With output:

```
   A     B
0  1     1
1  2     2
2  3    ''
3  4    45
4  5     0
```

Which is quite similar, but than I cannot replace the '' value with None:

```
df_d['B'].apply(lambda x: int(x) if x != '' else '').replace({'', None})
```

The '' still remains an empty string!

Can please someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Pandas as some new datatypes that will handle this all [nullable datatypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) however, it does state that is still "experimental".  Look at using `pd.Int54Dtype` otherwise pandas forces any column with a null to a float dtype.

Comment: There's no `None` or `Nan` equivalent of `int` types.  If your column contains null data it cannot be type `int`, it would be an `object` mix type.  Since you only care about replacing the `''` to `None`, you could do `df_d.loc[df_d['B'].eq(''), 'B'] = None` instead.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the reply!
@r.ook near... if your answer is applied to integer columns they suddenly become float!

Comment: As @ScottBoston mentioned, if an `int` type column has null data `pandas` will coerce it into `float` dtype.  You can recast it as mix type `astype('object')`.